# jquery ui sortable - sort by attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

If I'm running jquery ui and using sortable in a ul element:

```
$("#example").sortable({
    update: function () {
        //do something
    }
});

<ul id="example">
<li data-ex="1.1"></li>
<li data-ex="0.1"></li>
<li data-ex="1.4"></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to trigger an event that sorts my elements by the data attribute on the fly? Essentially I'd like a button that sorts the li elements by the data attribute also also triggers the update in sortable().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").sortable({//Sortable initialisation
        update: function () {
            updatehandler();//Custom function which handles sortable update.
        }
    });
    $('a').click(function () {// Click handler to sort
        var list = $('#example');
        var listItems = list.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).attr('data-ex') - $(b).attr('data-ex');
        });
        list.find('li').remove();
        list.append(listItems);
        updatehandler();//Call updatehandler after sorting
        return false;
    });    
});

function updatehandler() {
    //Your update handler code.
    alert('updated');
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="">Sort</a>
<ul id="example">
    <li data-ex="1.1">1.1</li>
    <li data-ex="0.1">0.1</li>
    <li data-ex="1.4">1.4</li>
</ul>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/151/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with sortable, but this fiddle shows how you can get the data-ex attribute's value, and define a variable to use for sorting in the plugin: 
http://jsfiddle.net/FF7z6/

I added `class="sort"` to your html, and then we get the value by using the following:

```
var dataEx;
$('.sort').click(function(){
var dataEx = $(this).attr("data-ex");
alert(dataEx);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense, it doesn't help with the sorting and there is no "sortby" method anyway in jquery ui's sortable